# Releasing crawled data: Potential legal challenge?

Tags: publications, ethics, computer-science, copyright, legal-issues

In many occasions in computer science I saw papers that analyze social network data also released these data, such as

http://socialnetworks.mpi-sws.org/data-imc2007.html

http://socialcomputing.asu.edu/datasets/BlogCatalog3

without explicit license granting. My question is: Will practices like these face potential legal challenges? For example, YouTube terms state that:

> You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.

where Content is defined as:

> “Content” includes the text, software, scripts, graphics, photos, sounds, music, videos, audiovisual combinations, interactive features and other materials you may view on, access through, or contribute to the Service.

Comment: In theory, the respective researchers *may* have asked YouTube for explicit authorization, which, in the case of research projects, *might* have been granted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the legality of a particular practice.  This kind of question would need to be posed on a law forum, and it would require supplementary information (jurisdiction, etc.) to answer.

Comment: I am closing this question for several reasons: 1) The legality of this is not of specific interest to academics or something that academics (in general) would be particularly knowledgeable about. 2) It is unclear why you are assuming that releasing is a problem as such. The quoted excerpt from the terms is about crawling the data, i.e., the main conflict arises upon gathering the data, not upon releasing it. — For the second reason I won’t migrate to [law.se]. If you want this question on [law.se], please ask a new question addressing this issue.